# magento front end pagination not working for custom table join query collection

Tags: magento-1.9, php, pagination

i working with the custom collection pagination, its working much good for single table collection, but for the join query collection, the pagination is not working, below i give as much a information for your further consideration.

i having two table

```
flquestion(table 1):
-------------------
question_id
question_title
question_description
question_category

flquestion_answer(table 2) (one question have a multiple answers)
-------------------------
answer_id
quesiton_id
answer_description
```

### my query using query buider :

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, COUNT(main_table.question_id) AS `total_answer` FROM `flquestion` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `flquestion_answer` AS `answer` ON main_table.question_id = answer.question_id where main_table.status=1 GROUP BY `main_table`.`question_id` ORDER BY `main_table`.`question_id` desc
```

when i run this query i got the full result (nearly 7 records having), but the pagination not working properly , for more information see below my screen shot and the block file code

### code in block file

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('flquestion/question')->getAllQuestion();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
}

public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}

protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
    $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all'));
    $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
    $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
    $load = $this->getCollection()->load();
    return $this;
}
```

### screen shot

[image]

Comment: where are you add join query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is the `group by` statement.
Magento's pagination system does not play well withe `group by` statements. You will always get a wrong result for the number of items.

You need to reset the `group by` in the select that calculates the total number of items.
This can be achieved by adding the following method in the collection resource model for your main entity (`question` in this case).

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $countSelect = parent::getSelectCountSql();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
    return $countSelect;
}
```

Actually you can add this method for all your collection resource models.
You will find the collection resource model in `[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Resource/[Entity]/Collection.php`.